# Scale analysis for the vertical component of the Boussinesq equation to obtain a complete hydrostatic relation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves

This is actually an exam question which i have been trying to solve for my studies. Consider the Boussinesq vertical equation:

\begin{align} \frac{\partial \widetilde{w}}{\partial t} = - \frac{1}{\bar{\rho}}\frac{\partial \widetilde{p}}{\partial z}-\frac{\widetilde{\rho}}{\bar{\rho}}g,\end{align}

where $\widetilde{w}$ is the water wave perturbation, $\bar{\rho}$ is the mean density for the Boussinesq Approximation, $\widetilde{\rho}$ is the density perturbation, and $\widetilde{p}$ is the pressure perturbation. Show that through a scale analysis for the study of surface gravity waves, the equation takes the form:

\begin{align} 0= - \frac{1}{\bar{\rho}}\frac{\partial\widetilde{p}}{\partial z}-\frac{\widetilde{\rho}}{\bar{\rho}}g\end{align}

Should I consider the Local Rossby number for that matter (to get rid of my local acceleration)? I know that it is different from the Hydrostatic equation, due to the fact that even the pressure perturbation is hydrostatic and not only the average. I am quite lost actually

Comment: You should define scales for the velocity, density and pressure fluctuations and non-dimensionalize the equations. This will require you to define a time scale as well. This will give you a dimensionless number which for your case is either very large or very small such that you may neglect certain terms. Most likely you will require the continuity equation also to define part of the scales. The pressure scale is usually chosen such that the dimensionless pressure gradient is the same order as at least one other term in the equation (here the buoyancy term)